# Est-ce que les enfants se sont lavé(es) les mains ?

Tags: verbes, accord, participe-passé, verbes-pronominaux

Je fais des exercices dans un livre de grammaire, et il y a cette question :

> Est-ce que les enfants se sont __ les mains ? *lavé* ou *lavées*

La solution est "lavé".

Pourquoi "lavé" ?

Comment: En attendant d'avoir le temps d'écrire une réponse : http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_1_07_accord_du_participe_passe_des_verbes_pronominaux.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le verbe ne peut pas s'accorder avec "les mains" parce que "les mains" comme COD est placé après le verbe et la règle dit que le verbe s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec le COD si il est placé avant , donc il reste l'autre solution .

Comment: Je suis sûr que c'est bien connu, Qu'est ce que cela veut dire, *COD*?

Comment: @medica, COD c'est Complément d'Object Direct. L'équivalent anglais est Direct Object.

Comment: Dans mes souvenirs, la règle du COD ne s'applique qu'avec le verbe avoir. Le participe s'accordant toujours avec le sujet dans le cas du verbe être.

Comment: @変幻出没 - Merci! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Il y a 13 pages sur l'accord du participe passé dans le *Bon Usage* dont trois sur les verbes pronominaux.  Pour le cas qui nous concerne (916, a dans la douzième édition):

> Quoique les verbes pronominaux se conjuguent avec l'auxiliaire *être*, ils peuvent être transitifs et assimilables aux verbes conjugués avec *avoir*, c'est-à-dire que leur participe s'accorde avec le complément d'objet direct si celui-ci précède.

*se laver les mains* est bien un usage transitif, l'accord éventuel se fera avec les mains mais comme ces mots sont placés après, il n'y a pas d'accord.

> Les enfants se sont lavé les mains.
>
> Les mains que les enfants ne s'étaient pas lavées étaient d'une saleté repoussante et leur mère les renvoya à la salle de bain.

Comment: The first “cas d'accord" in Toto’s deleted answer mentions agreement w/the subject when a [reflexive] subject does the action on itself. The example in question seems to still have the children washing [a part of] themselves, so does this mean that the rule concerning “subject/participle” agreement only applies when there is no COD? (or is the “when the subject does the action on itself” part of that rule interpreted strictly & action on “les mains” doesn’t qualify as “action on itself”?) (Or when there is no COD is the "se" treated as a preceding COD taking the gender/number of the subject?)

Comment: _Or when there is no COD is the "se" treated as a preceding COD taking the gender/number of the subject?_ that's a way to see it.  _Elle se sont lavées_ but _elles se sont lavé les mains_. The rules are quite arbitrary (search in @Laure's answers, IIRC she has a link to a document using simpler alternate rules)

Comment: The rules are not so arbitrary as it can seem. Le participe passé s'accorde avec "ce qui est". Si c'est le sujet (cas habituel de l'auxiliaire "être", mais pas dans le cas "se sont lavé[e][s]"), ça s'accorde toujours. Si c'est le COD (cas habituel de l'auxiliaire avoir), on ne fait l'accord qui si en écrivant le PP on connaît déjà ce avec quoi il faut accorder, donc si le COD est avant le PP. Si l'accord doit se faire avec le pronom "en", on considère que "en" est masculin singulier même si "en" remplace un nom qui n'est pas masculin singulier (_Des violettes, nous en avons cueilli_).